# How to Display each name Last line from a text file

Tags: c#

I want to display the last line of each name.  There are many names in a text file, the one name contains more than 50 lines.  I want to display each name last line from a text file.

please check this link you all will get idea.

[image]

there are names such as butter and apple.  butter contains 9 lines and apple contains apple contains 22 lines.  I want to Display the 9th line of the butter and 22nd line in apple

Thanks In Advance.

I am using  this code  to display all lines , but I want to Display the 9th line of the butter and 22nd line in apple.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int counter = 0;
    string line;

    // Read the file and display it line by line. 
    System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader("c:\\tra\\20100901.txt");
    while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        if (line.Contains("apple"))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(counter.ToString() + ": " + line);
        }

        counter++;
    }

    file.Close();  
}
```

Comment: So, what have you tried to do?

Comment: I don't understand what you want to do, and what do all the numbers in the text file mean?

Comment: I want to display  the  Apple,butter ,Lastlines

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static string ReturnTheNameBetweenCommas(string str)
{
    int indexOfTheFirstComma = str.IndexOf(',');//find the first comma index
    string strAfterTheFirstComma = str.SubString(indexOfTheFirstComma +1);//take the rest after the first comma
    indexOfTheFirstComma = strAfterTheFirstComma.IndexOf(',');
    string theNameBetweenFirstTwoCommas = strAfterTheFirstComma.SubString(0,indexOfTheFirstComma-1);

  return strAfterTheFirstComma;       

}

public class NameAndOccurence
{
    public string Name{ get; set; }
    public int Occurence{ get; set; }
}

public static void Method()
{
    List<string> listOfLines = new List<string>();
    //Read all the lines to listOfLines one by one, use listOfLines.Add(line) every line as an element of the list
    List<string> listOfDistinctNames = new List<string>();

    foreach(var item in listOfLines)
    {
         string nameInTheLine = ReturnTheNameBetweenCommas(item);

         if(!listOfDistinctNames.Contains(nameInTheLine))
         {
           listOfDistinctNames.Add(nameInTheLine);
         }
    }

    List<NameAndOccurence> listOfNameAndOccurence = new List<NameAndOccurence>();

    foreach(var nameStr in listOfDistinctNames)
    {
       NameAndOccurence nameAndOccr = new NameAndOccurence();

       int occurence = 0        

       foreach(var lineStr in listOfLines)
       {
           if(lineStr.Contains(nameStr))
           {
              occurence++;
           }
           else
           {
               nameAndOccr.Name = nameStr;
               nameAndOccr.Occurence = occurence;

               listOfNameAndOccurence.Add(nameAndOccr);                   
           }
       }

    }
    //now you've got the names in the lines and how many times they occurred
    //for example for the image you showed there are 10 lines with the name of Butter-1M
    //so in your listOfNameAndOccurence you have an object like this
    //nameAndOccurence.Name is "Butter-1M" and nameAndOccurence.Occurence is 10
    //you've got one for Apple too.
    //Well after that all you gotta do is writing the 10th line of the textfile for Butter-1M

}
```

Is it clear?

Comment: Which reference i need to add for List<NameAndOccurence> listOfNameAndOccurence = new List<NameAndOccurence>();

Comment: @SharrokG you don't need any it is just the class is NameAndOccurencce but when creating new instance it is NameAndOccurence ^_^.

Comment: @SharrokG I deleted one c from the class name, it must be ok.

Comment: how should i call these can u Please Help me please update in my your code